# pgsql 1 to n relation into json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, left-join, hstore

Long story short, how can i use 1 to n select data to build json like shown in example:

```
SELECT table1.id AS id1,table2.id AS id2,t_id,label 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.t_id = table1.id 

result 
|id1|id2|t_id|label|
+---+---+----+-----+
|1  | 1 | 1  | a   |
|   | 2 | 1  | b   |
|   | 3 | 1  | c   |
|   | 4 | 1  | d   |
|2  | 5 | 2  | x   |
|   | 6 | 2  | y   |
```

turn into this

```
 SELECT table1.id, build_json(table2.id,table2.label) AS json_data 
 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.t_id = table1.id  
 GROUP BY table1.id

|id1|json_data
+--+-----------------
|1 |{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c","4":"d"}
|2 |{"5":"x","6":"y"}
```

My guess the best start woulb be building an array from columns

**Hstore instead of json would be ok too**

Answer (score 0):

well your table structure is a bit strange (is looks more like report than table), so I see two tasks here:

**Replace nulls** with correct `id1`. You can do it like this

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        sum(case when id1 is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by t_id) as id1_partition,
        id1, id2, label
    from Table1  
), cte2 as (
    select
        first_value(id1) over(partition by id1_partition) as id1,
        id2, label
    from cte1
)
select *
from cte2
```

Now you have to **aggregate data** into `json`. As far as I remember, there's no such a function in PostgreSQL, so you have to concatenate data manually:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        sum(case when id1 is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by t_id) as id1_partition,
        id1, id2, label
    from Table1  
), cte2 as (
    select
        first_value(id1) over(partition by id1_partition) as id1,
        id2, label
    from cte1
)
select
   id1,
   ('{' || string_agg('"' || id2 || '":' || to_json(label), ',') || '}')::json as json_data
from cte2
group by id1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0f3d6/16)</kbd>**

And if you want to **convert into hstore**:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        sum(case when id1 is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by t_id) as id1_partition,
        id1, id2, label
    from Table1  
), cte2 as (
    select
        first_value(id1) over(partition by id1_partition) as id1,
        id2, label
    from cte1
)
select
    c.id1, hstore(array_agg(c.id2)::text[], array_agg(c.label)::text[])
from cte2 as c
group by c.id1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0f3d6/22)</kbd>**